# AEM 6.2: Using LinkTransformer - How is it triggered?

Tags: aem

I am looking at an [Adobe forum post](http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.15.html/forum__guhi-we_have_a_dialogto.html) where the link rewrite is happening. How is the LinkTransformer class triggered? For example if I am testing this in local, and put a debug inside the class does a page refresh get to this class?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Link Transformer will run on every request that renders HTML. It is used to rewrite all of the configured HTML elements.

It will for example rewrite the `href` attribute of all `<a>` HTML tags. But there are several more HTML elements and attributes that are rewritten.

So in theory your debugger should halt at a breakpoint on every request. (Except if you call the page through the Dispatcher which usually will cache the HTML after the first request. So every subsequent request would not be answered by AEM and therefore, the debugger will not halt.)